# Eclipse PDT - Failed to load JavaHL Library

Tags: eclipse

all of the sudden, when I work in my Eclipse PDT I get this error msg, not sure where they came from nor how to get rid of them

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mp:~ alexus$ ls -l /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.jnilib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  40 Nov 12 00:20 /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.jnilib -> /opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib

mp:~ alexus$ ls -l /opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 alexus  wheel  22 Nov 12 00:20 /opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib -> libsvnjavahl-1.0.dylib

mp:~ alexus$ ls -l /opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.dylib 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  663784 Aug 26 11:48 /opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.dylib
```

Answer (score 4):

Following an update to subclipse, I got that error on Ubuntu 9.10. In order to fix it, i had to adjust the path in the *config.ini* file.

First, locate your libsvjavahl-1 library :

```
sudo updatedb
locate libsvnjavahl-1
```

Mine was under `/usr/local/lib`

Then edit the path in the *config.ini*. You have to pass the libsvnjavahl-1 path to the JVM.

Locate *eclipse.ini* and edit the path and add, UNDER the line : -vmargs

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: i actually figure out, i created symlink.. but now its complaining that my lib is v1 and it needs v1.6+

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error on Windows 64-bit when adding a repository location. My fix was to install [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download).

I still had the error up in Eclipse while I installed SlikSVN. Once it was done I closed the message in Eclipse, and it successfully finished adding the repository location; I didn't even have to retry adding it or restart Eclipse.